# Unknown option '-rock' , and others when choosing random ('rock', 'paper', 'scissors') for computer

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this method run when a Button(event) happens. It tells me the choices are unknown options. I have searched for the error with no luck.

```
computer = StringVar()
computer.set('')

def computer_choice():
    choices = ('rock', 'paper', 'scissors')
    random_choice = randint(0, 2)
    computer.configure(choices[random_choice])

#This will show up for all options.
TclError: unknown option "-rock"
```

Comment: can you show more code, so we know what computer is? Its obviously some sort of tkinter widget, which doesnt take the arguments, you provide for it. What are you actually trying to do? if you want to set text, why not use a `StringVar`?

Comment: can you show us computer.configure method there some problem. The function that you have given here seems fine

Comment: What is `computer.configure`?

Comment: `computer.configure` is not his own method. It's the method of a `tkinter` widget. That's why you get the Tcl error message and why it does some weird stuff with that parameter (like transform it into `-rock`).

Comment: `computer.configure(text=choices[random_choice])` should fix it if you just want to show the choice as text

Comment: to get a full list of `configure` options like `text`, use `computer.keys()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing from your code, I think you want to do the following instead.

```
computer = StringVar()
computer.set('')

def computer_choice():
    choices = ('rock', 'paper', 'scissors')
    random_choice = randint(0, 2)
    computer.set(choices[random_choice])
```

Which can also be simpliefied using the random.choice method

```
computer = StringVar()
computer.set('')

def computer_choice():
    choices = ('rock', 'paper', 'scissors')
    computer.set(random.choice(choices))
```